# Programmatically changing checkbox does not fire change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code here:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="gridlines"]').change(function () {
    alert('hello world');
});

$('#gridlines').prop('checked', true);
```

When I load my page, the checkbox is checked, but the "hello world" does not get prompted.

However, when I click on the checkbox manually, "hello world" gets prompted.

What gives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to call [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/#change) or use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger the `change` event when values are changed through code.

Using `.change()`

```
$('#gridlines').prop('checked', true).change();
```

Using `.trigger()`

```
$('#gridlines').prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 5):

That is how it is suppose to work, only user interaction is support to trigger the change event

You can trigger it manually using [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)/[.trigger('change')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/);

```
$('#gridlines').prop('checked', true).change();
```

[change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value.