# Detect radio changes made by code with on method

Tags: jquery

I'm doing some BI work on a website. A web page contains some radio buttons that are being checked programatically when the user clicks the box that contains it.

**Therefore I can't make changes to the html or to the function that checks the radio when the user clicks the div**:

```
<form>
  <div><input type="radio" name="a" value="1" checked>1</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="a" value="2">2</div>
</form>

jQuery('form > div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Now I'm trying to write some code to be injected on this page. This code needs to detect the radio changes, but unless the user clicks the radio itself, the jQuery on method can't detect it.

```
jQuery('form > div').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function() {
    console.log(1234);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6n3roqw/

How can I solve this?

Comment: you could trigger a change event after setting the radio checked property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically changing checkbox does not fire change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236155/programmatically-changing-checkbox-does-not-fire-change-event)

Comment: So you can't rewrite the functions (as you wrote on my deleted answer), and can't change the HTML. Are there any other limitations we should know of?!

Comment: Yes, i need those divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger a change event after you change the radio's checked property, like so:

```
jQuery('form > div').on('click', function() {
        var element = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
    element.prop('checked', true);
    element.change();
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/35Lj814e/1/)

Comment: I can't change that function.

Comment: @incompleteness - are you able to change the function that has the console log in it?  If so, change it to trigger when the div is clicked, not when the radio is changed.  Like so:  `jQuery('form > div').on('click', function() {
 console.log(1234);
});`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).find('input[type=radio]').trigger('change');`